# Which datatype should I use?

Tags: c++

I'm really new to C++ and I'm having a confusion over something.
What I've achieved so far is:

- Created a class named CPlayer

What I want to do next is:

- Create a datatype (array/map/or whatever) to store the CPlayer in for each individual player. (PS: Each player can have an entirely different ID from the other player, for example: player1 has ID 1, player2 has ID 5)

In Squirrel I could do:

```
local playerInfo = {}; // Create a table
playerInfo[ playerId ]      <-  CPlayer();
// To remove it -
playerInfo.rawdelete( playerId );
```

Not sure what would be best in C++ to reproduce this.

Comment: You could use a `std::map<int,CPlayer>` where the key is the player ID.

Comment: Mind this little graph could help you make a choice: [STL choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G70oT.png).

Comment: If the number of players, `n` is known at compile time, `CPlayer playerInfo[n];`  to create an array, and and then used as `playerInfo[i]` where `i` is and `int` between `0` and `n-1`.    If `n` is not known until run time (e.g. its value can change) use `std::vector<CPlayer> playerinfo(n)`, which can then be used as `playerinfo[i]` for `i` between `0` and `n-1`.   Note the round and square brackets - their usage is important, and misuse will be catastrophic.  If identifers vary, use `std::map<int, CPlayer> playerinfo` and `playerinfo[i]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having just looked up what a table is in Squirrel, and from reading the question above it seems the C++ version of what you want is

```
#include <map>

std::map<int, CPlayer> playerInfo;
```

The equivalent of `playerInfo[ playerId ] <- CPlayer();` would be

```
playerInfo[playerId] = CPlayer();
```

and the equivalent of `playerInfo.rawdelete( playerId );` would be

```
playerInfo.erase(playerId);
```

More information [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::map as shown below. Below sample should give fair idea on the usage.

```
std::map<into, PlayersInfo> mapPlayerInfo:
int nPlayerId1 = 1; // Player 1 Id sample
int nPlayerId2 = 2; // Player 2 Id sample

PlayerInfo player1(nPlayerId1,...); // Additional arguments to constructor if required
mapPlayerInfo[nPlayerId1] = player1;

PlayerInfo player2(nPlayerId2,...); // Sample 2
mapPlayerInfo[nPlayerId2] = player2;

//Deleting based on player Id
mapPlayerInfo.erase(nPlayerId1);
```